How to prevent the same machine to have two rows of data but for a selected condition it will be allowed?

The machines supposedly cannot be duplicated in the DataGridView but for certain condition it can be allowed.
while (read.Read())
            {
                if (read["Selected_Problem"] != DBNull.Value && read["Selected_Problem"].ToString() == "#Temperature Monitoring")
                {
                    submitToPending2();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This machine has been notified to Technician.')", true);

                    if (read.HasRows)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This machine is currently under the status Pending or Processing. You cannot submit it again.')", true);
                        clearTextBox();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        submitToPending2();
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This machine has been notified to Technician.')", true);
                        //Response.Redirect("operatorView.aspx");
                    }

                    //read.Close();
                    //con.Close();
                }
            }
            read.Close();
            con.Close();while (read.Read())
            {
                if (read["Selected_Problem"] != DBNull.Value && read["Selected_Problem"].ToString() == "#Temperature Monitoring")
                {
                    submitToPending2();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This machine has been notified to Technician.')", true);

                    if (read.HasRows)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This machine is currently under the status Pending or Processing. You cannot submit it again.')", true);
                        clearTextBox();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        submitToPending2();
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This machine has been notified to Technician.')", true);
                        //Response.Redirect("operatorView.aspx");
                    }

                    //read.Close();
                    //con.Close();
                }
            }
            read.Close();
            con.Close();

It can be duplicated only after the problem of '#Temperature Monitoring' but just for once.

What's the problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
